Proving that going around the circle 'n' times is not homotopic to going around 'm' times?( Brute force)
I am trying to convince myself that the fundamental group of the circle really is $\mathbb{Z}$. So, I want to prove that the loops in the homotopy class of loops that go around $m$ times can not be homotopic to the loops that go around $n$ times.
A loop that go around $m$ times can be written as $f: \left[0,1 \right] \to S^1 , f(t)= e^{2 i\pi m t}$ and $n$ times can be written as $g: \left[0,1 \right] \to S^1, g(t)= e^{2i\pi n t}$. I must now prove that there is no continuous function $H : \left[ 0 , 1 \right]^2 \to S^1$ with the property that $H(0,\lambda)=1$, $H(t,0)=f(t)$ and  $H(t,1)=g(t)$.
I can't figure out on what idea I can show the non existence here. Could some ideas be given?
[Note: Of course, I am looking for arguements which don't use already the fact that fundamental group of the circle is $\mathbb{Z}$.]

Remark: There exist these related questions related to gaining intuition on fundamental group of circle 1 , 2

There is no better way than to pass to its universal cover.

I want to see a brute force approach @Randall

If you know that $\int_\gamma dz/z$ depends on $\gamma$ only up to homotopy in $\mathbb{C}\setminus {0}$, you can use that.

It's hard to brute force something to show that such a thing [i.e., a homotopy] does not exist.  Hence, passing to the cover.   I hope you get a decent and clever answer, though.  [@anomaly 's tactic is the nicest.]

Maybe this doesn't meet your criteria, but I find it very convincing to just consider the winding number, which must vary continuously (and therefore not at all) as we deform the curve.

I am not sure if this is considered bruteforce, but consider the following approach.
We are going to use a theorem for multivariable calculus (for a proof, see here)

Let $U$ be a connected region and $\Gamma$ be a piecewise smooth nullhomotopic loop in $U$. Also let $P$ and $Q$ be two functions with continuous partial derivatives and satisfying $P_x=Q_y$. Then $$\int_\Gamma P\mathrm dx+Q\mathrm dy=0$$

Now consider $\Gamma=f\circ g^{-1}$ (concatenation) and note that if $f\sim g$, then $\Gamma$ is nullhomotopic. Let $$(P,Q)=\left(\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}, \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\right)$$ and $U=\mathbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$. All the conditions of the theorem are satisfied and hence the integral should be $0$ over $\Gamma$.
But doing the integral by hand tells you it should be $m-n$. Thus $m=n$. Hence if they are homotopic, the numbers have to match. The converse is trivially true.
This is essentially the same answer as the winding number method mentioned in the comments, but just with calculus.

This is just a rephrasing of the answer from anamoly

Yes, I mentioned that at the end of the answer. I just wanted to avoid the complex analysis language.

Assume you have loops $\alpha'$ and $\beta'$, where the first goes around the circle m-times and the second one n-times, you know those are homotopic to $\alpha=e^{2 \pi i m t}$ and $\beta=e^{2 \pi i n t}$, then $\alpha \overline{\beta}$ is homotopic to a loop that goes around the circle $m-n$ times.
Let us only check the case, when $m-n=1$, so why is a loop that goes around a circle once not homotopic to a constant loop. Denote it by $e_1$.
Let $x_0\in S^1$ be a basepoint. Suppose there exists such homotopy $H:I\times I \rightarrow S^1$, such that $H(0,s)=e_1(s)$, $H(1,s)=cst_{x_0}$. H is a homotopy (rel $\delta I$), therefore also $H(t,0)=x_0$ and $H(t,1)=x_0$.
So to visualise, we have a map from $I^2$ to $S^1$, where the bottom side wraps around the circle once and the upper, the left and the right side map to a single point. If we denote with $\sim$ a relation $x \sim y$, when $x$ and $y$ are points on before mentioned three sides, then H is equivalent to a map
$H^{'}$ from  $I^2/{_\sim}$  to $S^1$, but $I^2/{_\sim}$ is homeomorphic to a 2 dimensional disc $D^2$, with one side (the one that was on the bottom of $I^2$), that wraps around $S^1$ once. So now you have a map
$$H':D^2 \rightarrow S^1,$$ such that $H'|_{S^1}=Id_{S^1}$, but that would mean, that you could retract $D^2$ to it's boundry sphere, which is not possible according to Brouwer's fixed point theorem.
I suppose similiar approach can be used when m-n>1.
