Showing that the loop the straight across the torus is not homotopic to the loop that goes straight around
Here is a picture to explain what I mean by across and around:

I can quite easily prove that any around loop is homotopic to each other, and that any across loop is homotopic to each other. I spell out the method to prove that any straight across loop is homotopic.
Remark: For simplicity I am considering only paths that go around once that completes the loop in one second.

We construct the torus as the quotient space of the rectangle. In the quotient rectangle, any across loop could be thought of as going straight up (well there is a convention matter here, you could take it strictly horizontally as well..). I draw two across loop in it:

The parameterization of these paths in the rectangle are $L_1(t)= \begin{pmatrix} a \\\ t\end{pmatrix}$ and $L_1(t)= \begin{pmatrix} b \\\ t\end{pmatrix}$. Following this by the projection $\pi$ corresponding to the equivalence relation for torus, we get the path on the torus.
The homotopy between these two is given as $H= \pi \bigg( L_1+ \lambda (L_1 - L_2) \bigg) $

Now, for the question we must show that there is no homotopy between an across loop$ \begin{pmatrix} a \\\ t\end{pmatrix}$ and an around loop $\begin{pmatrix} t \\\ b\end{pmatrix}$ but I am confusesd in this question as much as I was in this one on how to show a non existence of the homotopy.
I am presuming that the fact the fundamental group of the torus is $Z \times Z$ implies the non existence somehow... but I just can't see how. Help?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4972709/proving-that-going-around-the-circle-n-times-is-not-homotopic-to-going-around

Are you aware that the torus is $S^1 \times S^1$? ...also, the fundamental group of the torus is not $S^1 \times S^1$ but rather $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.

Hint: use the cover $\mathbb{R} \times S^1 \to T^2$ given by $(x, y) \mapsto (e^{2i\pi x}, y)$.

My bad @Ben Steffan and yes altho I'd prefer something that elaborates it in the quotient implementation as I'm trying to gain a bit of feel for how it works in quotient spaces specifically

Is the problem impossible without covers? I asked  question about circle winding number previously and again it was about covers @NaïmFavier

@CantorDustDrachen The problem is more or less immediate if you treat it as $S^1 \times S^1$: One of your curves corresponds to $(1, 0)$ and the other to $(0, 1)$ in $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \cong \pi_1(S^1) \times \pi_1(S^1) \cong \pi_1(S^1 \times S^1)$ (the existing answer argues essentially like this, assuming less knowledge). No need to go to coverings, although you could also solve it that way. As for quotient spaces, one major technique in dealing with quotient spaces is to find a homotopy equivalence to a space you know better, so this is entirely in line :)

Of course if you want to rely on the fact that $\pi_1(T^2) = \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ then you don't need to talk about covers, but the proof of that uses covers. They are unavoidable in the following sense: synthetically (in homotopy type theory), you need the univalence axiom to prove that e.g. $\pi_1(S^1) = \mathbb{Z}$; without univalence, it is consistent that $S^1$ is contractible. Univalence in this setting is related to descent, which says something about the type families you can have over $S^1$, which can be interpreted as covers.

If I have two homotopic closed curves $\gamma_1, \gamma_2 \colon [0,1] \to X$, then after post-composing with some continuous $f\colon X \to Y$, we know that $f \circ \gamma_1$ and $f \circ \gamma_2$ are still homotopic.
In your case, $X=S^1 \times S^1$, so let's use $Y=S^1$ and define $f\colon S^1 \times S^1 \to S^1$ by $f(a, b) = a$.
Your curves are $\gamma_1(t) = (e^{2\pi i t}, 1) \in S^1 \times S^1$ and $\gamma_2(t) = (1, e^{2\pi i t})$ -- note that there are various notations to use depending on how exactly you want to write down the points of $S^1$, whether that's as $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ or $[0,1]/\sim$ or $\{e^{2\pi i t} : t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ but they'll all work essentially the same way.
Composing with $f$ gives two curves $f \circ \gamma_1(t) = e^{2 \pi i t}$ and $f \circ \gamma_2(t) = 1$. So you are left to show that the constant curve $t\mapsto 1$ in $S^1$ is not homotopic to the curve $t\mapsto e^{2\pi i t}$ in $S^1$ that winds around once.
One way of doing this is to show that they have different winding numbers, namely $0\neq 1$, so $f \circ \gamma_1 \not\simeq f \circ \gamma_2$, so we conclude that $\gamma_1 \not\simeq \gamma_2$.
